# Waiting for output from a subprocess which does not terminate

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to run a subprocess from my script. The subprocess is an interactive (shell-like) application, to which I issue commands through the subprocess' `stdin`.
After I issue a command, the subprocess outputs the result to `stdout` and then waits for the next command (**but does not terminate**).

For example:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(args = [...], stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE, shell = False)
# Issue a command:
p.stdin.write('command\n')
# *** HERE: get the result from p.stdout ***
# CONTINUE with the rest of the script once there is not more data in p.stdout
# NOTE that the subprocess is still running and waiting for the next command
# through stdin.
```

My problem is getting the result from `p.stdout`. The script needs to get the output while there is new data in `p.stdout`; but once there is no more data, I want to continue with the script.
The subprocess does not terminate, so I cannot use `communicate()` (which waits for the process to terminate).
I tried reading from `p.stdout` after issuing the command, like this:

```
res = p.stdout.read()
```

But the subprocess is not fast enough, and I just get empty result.
I thought about polling `p.stdout` in a loop until I get something, but then how do I know I got everything? And it seems wasteful anyway.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using an asynchornous librry/framework such as circuits (Example: https://bitbucket.org/circuits/circuits-dev/src/tip/examples/ping.py)

Comment: @JamesMills, going asynchronous could work, but I think it will over complicate what I want to do. I will do it if no other solution presents itself. Thanks.

Comment: The only other way would be to use a thread to hide the blocking call. Any otehr option is going to involve some kind of concurrency/asynchronous library/framework. You may as well use one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating several options I reached two solutions:

1. Setting the subprocess' stdout stream to be non blocking by using the `fcntl` module.
2. Using a thread to collect the subprocess' output to a proxy queue, and then reading the queue from the main thread.

I describe both solutions (and the problem and its origin) in [this post](http://blog.eyalarubas.com/2013/12/11/non-blocking-reading-from-a-subprocess-output-stream-in-python/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `gevent.subprocess` in gevent-1.0 to substitute the standard `subprocess` module. It could do the concurrency tasks using synchronous logic and won't block the script. Here is a brief tutorial about [gevent.subprocess](http://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/#subprocess)

Comment: My problem is not with concurrency and synchronicity. I have clarified the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `circuits.io.Process` in [circuits-dev](https://bitbucket.org/circuits/circuits-dev) to wrap an asynchronous call to subprocess.

Example: https://bitbucket.org/circuits/circuits-dev/src/tip/examples/ping.py

Comment: Thanks James, but the problem is not with with concurrency and synchronicity. I have clarified the question.

Comment: I don't think there's necessarily an "easy" answer to this.